# How to target a div using content inside the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, insertafter

I have 2 divs with same class name but different strings inside the div. I want to use an insertAfter the first div to display some additional text, but the text is being displayed under both divs:

```html
<div class='test'>First Div</div>
<div class='test'>Second Div</div>
```

My approach:

```js
if ( document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0] 
  && document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0].innerHTML == 'First Div'
   ) {
     $('<h2>Inserting New Text</h2>').insertAfter('.test')[0];
   }
```

But this adds the text after both the First Div and the Second Div. I want to know if there is a way to insert only once or insert after matching the string

Comment: Why are you using a mix of native DOM methods and jQuery? Why not keep things consistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep it simple, find all elements with target class and pick the first one:

```js
const el = document.getElementsByClassName('test')
$('<div>new text</div>').insertAfter(el[0])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='test'>First Div</div>
<div class='test'>Second Div</div>
```

Comment: If you're using jQuery why use `getElementsByClassName`?

Comment: Because I hate jQuery and only used it because OP is using it and `insertAfter` isn't available with Vanilla JS (only `insertBefore`).

Comment: `const el = document.querySelector('.test'); el.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div>new text</div>');`

Answer (score 1):

You can ask javascript to find the elements of the class and then convert the result into an array and find the first element that matches your condition.

```js
const elements = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("test"));

const target = elements.find(el => el.innerHTML === 'First Div');

$('<h2>Inserting New Text</h2>').insertAfter(target);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='test'>First Div</div>
<div class='test'>Second Div</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for jQuery here. Use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) to add the new element.

```js
// Pick up the first element with the test class
const el = document.querySelector('.test');

// Use `insertAdjacentHTML` to add the new div after it
el.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div>new text</div>');
```

```html
<div class="test">First Div</div>
<div class="test">Second Div</div>
```